# No authorized orgs after opening a project folder

Tags: salesforcedx

I have about 10 project folders. In each I used SFDX: Create Project and then SFDX: Authorize an Org.

When I use File -> Open Folder and open any of those 10 project folders, I loose:

1. Authorized Org
2. Can not use SFDX: Authorize an Org (the command is missing, I'd apparently have to use SFDX: Create Project again.)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Problem was that I did not open the folder of the project, but I opened a folder above the folder of the project. So given that the path would be:

***C:\Documents\Something\ProjectFolder1***

Correct folder opened: *C:\Documents\Something\ProjectFolder1*

Incorrect folder opened: *C:\Documents\Something*

Conclusion:
Salesforce DX will connect automatically after opening the project folder.